# Exchanging columns with rows when counting missing values

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I want to write a function which calculates missing values in data frame. In output I want to have data frame with missing values calculated. Let's take code following :

```
total_missing<-function(data){
  (colSums(is.na(data)))
}

x<-rnorm(100)
y<-runif(100)
z<-rexp(100)
x[51]<-NA
x[57]<-NA
y[61]<-NA
y[62]<-NA
z[10]<-NA
df1<-data.frame(x,y,z)
> total_missing(df1)
x y z 
2 2 1
```

But now it's not a data frame. To check that I simply used

```
> class(total_missing(df1))
[1] "numeric"
```

So then the first idea was to use

```
> as.data.frame((total_missing(df1)))
  (total_missing(df1))
x                    2
y                    2
z                    1
```

And I have data frame! Problem is that I have variables in rows and missing values in columns and I do not like that solution. I was trying to change rows to columns but the problem is this data frame contains only one column, so everything is connected (it's hard to divide). Do you have any idea what should be done to get in output :

```
>proper_data_frame
x y z 
2 2 1 
class(proper_data_frame)="data.frame"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the output to dataframe by transposing :

```
total_missing<-function(data){
  as.data.frame(t(colSums(is.na(data))))
}

total_missing(df1)

#  x y z
#1 2 2 1
class(total_missing(df1))
#[1] "data.frame"
```

You can do this in `dplyr` as well :

```
library(dplyr)
total_missing<-function(data){
  data %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~sum(is.na(.))))
}
```